# Can't access a class object from a function says unknown class

Tags: android, class, listview

Trying to fetch all the selected values from a list view which is stored in a class array. When I tried to fetch from that class and trying to create a object in a function I can't use it. Here is the code

```
public void showResult(View view) {
        String result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount=0;
        ArrayList<contactStruct> product = new ArrayList<contactStruct>();

        for (product p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.box){
                result += "\n" + p.name;
                totalAmount+=p.price;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, result+"\n"+"Total Amount:="+totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

it is within onCreate. It says unknown class product. Please help.
Yes its on the same package. Here is the class

```
public class contactStruct {
    String name;
    String mob;
    int image;
    boolean box;


    contactStruct(String _describe, String _mob, int _image, boolean _box) {
        name = _describe;
        mob = _mob;
        image = _image;
        box = _box;
    }
}
```

And Here is my complete code

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LoadContacts extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<contactStruct> products = new ArrayList<contactStruct>();
    Cursor cursor ;
    String name, phoneNumber;
    int imgP;
    ListAdapter boxAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_contacts);
        fillData();
        boxAdapter = new com.example.piku.SteaUd.ListAdapter(this, products);
        ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lview);
        lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
        Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.selectCon);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showResult(v);
            }
        });
    }

    void fillData() {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            imgP =cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
            products.add(new contactStruct(""+name,phoneNumber,imgP,false));

        }
        cursor.close();


    }

    public void showResult(View view) {
        String result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount=0;
        ArrayList<contactStruct> prod = new ArrayList<contactStruct>();

        for (prod p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.box){
                result += "\n" + p.name;
                totalAmount+=p.price;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, result+"\n"+"Total Amount:="+totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your class defined? Already tried ALT+ENTER ?

Comment: ALT+ENTER is not available

Comment: please try to clean project and rebuild it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to make the class unknown as public? I suggest you post your class **contactStruct**. maybe is not in the same package, it looks like at compile time is not recognized, but is just an assumption, if does not work  please post the entire error message

EDIT: OK  so what you need to know is to specify the Object p.

Possibly is:

```
for (ListAdapter p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
```

should work like this, the cycle for does not work like this you cannot pass `prod` or `product` to p.

For the future please study the official java documentation that teaches you how to use this [feature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: OK @DebasisMandal please see my Edit above, now it should be resolved this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be is in `showResult` in which you have

```
(prod p : boxAdapter.getBox())
```

in the for loop `prod` should be the type of the object p (the Class) while prod seems to be the arraylist object, but the IDE should give you an error there, in fact Android Studio tells me (writing the same thing) `Unknown class prod`

Plus make sure the boxAdapter is iterable

```
        com.example.piku.SteaUd.ListAdapter(this, products);
```

should implement Iterable.